# Add background image in Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to insert a full-width background image on this part of my page. Could someone please tell me which css rule i should follow? Because as far as i know you canot insert a background image inside a row. thanks

```html
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/profile.png" alt="">
                    <div class="intro-text">
                        <span class="name">HEADING</span>
                        <hr class="star-light">
                        <span class="skills">TEXT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Do you want to make an <img> tag image a background for Heading and Text part?

Comment: I think it's not unreal what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/yym7d1ov/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you want to add a background image, `<img>` is not the way to go. Use the [`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) property.

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" 
         style="background:transparent url('img/profile.png') no-repeat center center /cover">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <span class="name">HEADING</span>
          <hr class="star-light">
          <span class="skills">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Please note that adding inline style is not recommended, I used it demonstrative here. The proper way to style your div would be to add a specific class or an ID to it and style it inside your CSS files.

In the snippet above I used the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Formal_syntax) shorthand property to set the `background-image`. This shorthand allows setting background `color`, `image`, `repeat`, `origin`, `clip`, `position` and `size` in a single declaration. You can skip any of them, but `size` must be prefixed with a `/` and come right after `position`.

Comment: maybe consider `background-size: cover;` as well.

Comment: @walkerrandophsmith, Andrei's solution includes the `background-size` rule, but included in the shorthand version.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your css file the `background-image: url('img.png')` property to define it.

For more options take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).